# WooCommerce: Checkout page redirects to https on localhost

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I work on a local install of a WooCommerce website.
I need to work on checkout page but when I'm trying to go to this page it's make a redirect from:

`localhost/exmple.com/checkout/` - that works

To :

`https://localhost/exmple.com/checkout/` - that doesn't works

And have this error:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Reloading the page Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the
>   firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

In my install, every https URL is not working...

What I'm trying to do is to disable this redirection to **https** for the checkout page.

I'm trying to find it in `wp-config.php` or in `.htacces` files, but I didn't find it...

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: check under woocommerce->settings->checkout->force secure checkout - it might be that that option is enabled

Comment: @M.Doye - thanks - that was that!

Answer (score 6):

For WooCommerce version 3.6.5 go to WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced and uncheck "Force secure checkout".